# pandas read_csv index_col=None not working with delimiters at the end of each line

Tags: python, pandas

I am going through the 'Python for Data Analysis' book and having trouble in the 'Example: 2012 Federal Election Commision Database' section reading the data to a DataFrame. The trouble is that one of the columns of data is always being set as the index column, even when the index_col argument is set to None.

Here is the link to the data : http://www.fec.gov/disclosurep/PDownload.do.

Here is the loading code (to save time in the checking, I set the nrows=10):

```
import pandas as pd
fec = pd.read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv',nrows=10,index_col=None)
```

To keep it short I am excluding the data column outputs, but here is my output (please not the Index values):

```
In [20]: fec

Out[20]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 10 entries, C00410118 to C00410118
Data columns:
...
dtypes: float64(4), int64(3), object(11)
```

And here is the book's output (again with data columns excluded):

```
In [13]: fec = read_csv('P00000001-ALL.csv')
In [14]: fec
Out[14]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1001731 entries, 0 to 1001730
...
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(14)
```

The Index values in my output are actually the first column of data in the file, which is then moving all the rest of the data to the left by one. Would anyone know how to prevent this column of data to be listed as an index? I would like to have the index just +1 increasing integers.

I am fairly new to python and pandas, so I apologize for any inconvenience. Thanks.

Comment: This is too bad-- maybe they altered the form of the CSV file on the website in the last few months (I didn't make any modifications to it myself)?

Comment: in my case, i was setting index_col = 0, which didn't work and index_col=None did work

Comment: In my environment, `index_col=0` worked. `index_col=False` and `index_col=None` didn't work.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

### Quick Answer

Use `index_col=False` instead of `index_col=None` when you have delimiters at the end of each line to turn off index column inference and discard the last column.

### More Detail

After looking at the data, there is a comma at the end of each line. And this  quote (the documentation has been edited since the time this post was created):

> index_col: column number, column name, or list of column numbers/names, to use as the index (row labels) of the resulting DataFrame. By default, it will number the rows without using any column, unless there is one more data column than there are headers, in which case the first column is taken as the index.

from [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#column-and-index-locations-and-names) shows that pandas believes you have n headers and n+1 data columns and is treating the first column as the index.

---

EDIT 10/20/2014 - More information

I found [another valuable entry](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#index-columns-and-trailing-delimiters) that is specifically about trailing limiters and how to simply ignore them:

> If a file has one more column of data than the number of column names, the first column will be used as the DataFrame’s row names: ...
>
> Ordinarily, you can achieve this behavior using the index_col option.
>
> There are some exception cases when a file has been prepared with delimiters at the end of each data line, confusing the parser. To explicitly disable the index column inference and discard the last column, pass index_col=False: ...

Comment: You're right. All he needs to do is add one comma to the end of the header and the problem will be fixed. I deleted my post since it's incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the help craigts and juniper! I ended up dropping the last list item from the dataset as they were all null.

Comment: index_col=0 apply in my case.

Answer (score 109):

Re: craigts's response, for anyone having trouble with using either False or None parameters for index_col, such as in cases where you're trying to get rid of a range index, you can instead use an integer to specify the column you want to use as the index. For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

The above will set the first column as the index (and not add a range index in my "common case").

## Update

Given the popularity of this answer, I thought i'd add some context/ a demo:

```
# Setting up the dummy data
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2, 3], "B":[4, 5, 6]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [3]: df.to_csv('file.csv', index=None)
File[3]:
A  B
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Reading without index_col or with None/False will all result in a range index:

```
In [4]: pd.read_csv('file.csv')
Out[4]:
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

# Note that this is the default behavior, so the same as In [4]
In [5]: pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=None)
Out[5]:
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

In [6]: pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=False)
Out[6]:
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

However, if we specify that "A" (the 0th column) is actually the index, we can avoid the range index:

```
In [7]: pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
Out[7]:
   B
A
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

Comment: Just a heads up that this is not functionally equivalent to index_col=False. Use false if you want just a standard integer index on your dataset. Use 0 if you want to the first data column as the index. In the case of wanting the first data column as the index in a dataset that has extra delimiters, you need to set usecols and specify index_col=0. I will expand my answer soon to cover this issue.

Comment: Based, thanks, this one worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If pandas is treating your first row as a header, you can use header =  none as such:

```
df = pd.read_csv ("csv-file.csv", header=None)
```

this way pandas will treat your first row as like any row.