# How to prevent selecting first row as index column

Tags: python, pandas

I come to encounter a problem with reading my data the first column is assigned as index column even though I use `index_col=None` or `index_col=None`. Similar issue posted as [pandas read_csv index_col=None not working with delimiters at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960574/pandas-read-csv-index-col-none-not-working-with-delimiters-at-the-end-of-each-li)

```
raw_data = {'patient': ['spried & roy']*5,
            'obs': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
            'treatment': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
            'score': ['strong', 'weak', 'normal', 'weak', 'strong'],

            }
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['patient', 'obs', 'treatment', 'score'])

   patient  obs  treatment   score
0  spried & roy    1          0  strong
1  spried & roy    2          1    weak
2  spried & roy    3          0  normal
3  spried & roy    1          1    weak
4  spried & roy    2          0  strong
```

## writing df to csv with tab seperated format

```
df.to_csv('xgboost.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

## reading back again

```
read_df=pd.read_table(r'xgboost.txt', header=0,index_col=None, skiprows=0, skipfooter=0, sep="\t",delim_whitespace=True) 

read_df

         patient  obs  treatment   score
spried &     roy    1          0  strong
       &     roy    2          1    weak
       &     roy    3          0  normal
       &     roy    1          1    weak
       &     roy    2          0  strong
```

As we can see `patient` column separated into `spried &` and `roy` and `spried &` became index column even if I explicitly write `index_col=None`.

How can we correctly get `patient` column as it is and control index column exist or not ?

thx

Comment: Could you just use `pd.read_csv` ? `pd.read_csv('xgboost.txt', sep="\t")` seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `delim_whitespace=True`, because it use whitespaces separator instead `tab`s in your solution, but here working only `sep='\t'` parameter with file name:

```
df.to_csv('xgboost.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
read_df=pd.read_table(r'xgboost.txt', sep="\t") 
print (read_df)
        patient  obs  treatment   score
0  spried & roy    1          0  strong
1  spried & roy    2          1    weak
2  spried & roy    3          0  normal
3  spried & roy    1          1    weak
4  spried & roy    2          0  strong
```

Another idea is write to file whitespace separator, so `delim_whitespace=True` working nice:

```
df.to_csv('xgboost.txt', sep=' ', index=False)

read_df=pd.read_table(r'xgboost.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: Actually I need that part (delim_whitespace=True) because in my real data it is the only way to read column names correctly! I'm getting error if I remove it `"None of [Index( 
'patient', 'obs','treatment','score'], [dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Oh I see. Let me dig a little bit more. But thanks for `delim_whitespace=True` part.

Comment: @Alexander - Is possible create sample data with real data? the worse scenario is whitespace separators, whitespaces in data and in check data in csv there are not `"` like `"spried & roy" 1 0 strong`

Comment: I resolved the issue. I found that in real data there are white spaces in column names like `'patient '` so I did df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ','') and problem solved. Thanks for your guidance though and quick help!