# Is there a way to create an index column for a pandas df that is not one of my data columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a ton of data, 8 files each with about 30,000 rows, that I'm trying to import as a pandas dataframe. However, python does not create an index column, instead, it just uses my first column of data as the index. I need a separate column for the index, but can't find any way to do that. Is there something I can add during the

```
readdff = pd.read_csv("Rawdata01.txt",sep='\t',header=(0))
```

[image: This is what I get that I don't want.]

that will create one?

I have other problems as well. my data needs to be broken down into 1000 row sections with an 10 row header deleted each time. The person who exported this data took no thought about how it was going to be used. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a sample of what my raw data looks like.

```
Channels    1   
Samples 1000    
Date    2020/02/12  
Time    10:11:36.6395705499426038443    
Y_Unit_Label    Volts   
X_Dimension Time    
X0  0.0000000000000000E+0   
Delta_X 0.001000    
***End_of_Header***     
X_Value Voltage Comment
0.000000    4.930675    4.96V\0A69.0 cm\0A6.9 degrees
0.001000    4.934949
0.002000    4.931990
0.003000    4.923443
0.004000    4.914239
0.005000    4.911938
0.006000    4.913252
0.007000    4.917855
0.008000    4.919498
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(...,index_col=None)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas read\_csv index\_col=None not working with delimiters at the end of each line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960574/pandas-read-csv-index-col-none-not-working-with-delimiters-at-the-end-of-each-li)

Comment: _my data needs to be broken down into 1000 row sections with an 10 row header deleted each time._ The data goes: header -> 1000 rows -> header -> 1000 rows... ?