# Pandas, how to remove the very first column (ordered column)

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know how to name this column [red arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBCjx.png), it appears every time I import & export csv. The format I expect as following (without that ordered column) [expected format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPiDt.png).
That column is not in the list of columns as `df.columns`, it makes me confuse.
Any help is highly appreciated please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the index column. As you didn't specify `index_col` in `read_csv()`—at least I guess so since you didn't post any code, Pandas creates a unique index for each row.

Comment: Hi MK1986, sorry, here is my code 'pd.read_csv('Price.csv', index_col=None)[['date','open','high','low','close','volume']]'
I also tried 'df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)', that column is still there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960574/pandas-read-csv-index-col-none-not-working-with-delimiters-at-the-end-of-each-li?rq=1 maybe this helps you. Why does the index bother you?

Comment: A dataframe has to have an index. You can't get rid of it. If you want to delete that default ordered number for index, you have to specify one of the columns as an index for the entire dataframe, for instance you can put `date` column as the index :`df.set_index('date', drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you all, It is fixed just now. Yep, it is the auto index of pandas. What I've done are:  
I save it as `df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(ticker),index=None)`  
then I load it `pd.read_csv('file.csv',index_col=0)`  
I need the exact format for the pipeline ingest the local csv data, hopefully it works